# How to add default value to text field that cannot be changed (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a formatted text field that will have its contents then parsed into a Ruby Date object. I think I have the logic for taking a value from a text field and turning that into a date, but I can't figure out the formatting part.

I want a text field that would already have separators in it by default, that the user could not overwrite. So I would want the text field to look like:

```
__/__/__
```

And when they tab into the field, the text they type fills in the spaces instead of overwriting everything in there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

not sure about the ruby but you can use jQuery like so:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#key").mask("aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa");
});
```

and simply use `<noscript>` in your page header to make sure anyone's viewing your page has the javascript enabled.